# What's the story with two different "System.Configuration" references?

Tags: c#, configuration, libraries, using

In order to get more information from my Telerik Exceptions, I would like to adapt my configuration.

I have a working application, which does something like this:

```
using NLog;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
...
    var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
...
```

When I ask this application what that `ConfigurationManager` is, the tooltip reveals it being: "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager".

Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> for more information, I get information, starting with:

```
#region Assembly System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Configuration.dll
#endregion
```

Now I want to do the same thing in my other application:

```
using NLog;
using System;
...
using System.Configuration;
...
    var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
```

This is not working, because `ConfigurationManager` is believed being `NLog.Internal.ConfigurationManager`. When I clarify this (changing `ConfigurationManager` into `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`, that doesn't work because `System.Configuration` does not know about any `ConfigurationManager`. When I ask "What DO you know about?", I get an answer like `ClientSettingsSection`. Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> leads to this information:

```
#region Assembly System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// location unknown
// Decompiled with ICSharpCode.Decompiler 7.1.0.6543
#endregion
```

=> What is this? Why can't I access `System.Configuration` the same way in both applications? What can I do in order to get a `ConfigurationManager`?

(Both target .NET Framework 4.6.1.)

Comment: You have a reference on System.Configuration(.dll) in your second Application?

Comment: No, I don't, and that will be the solution indeed. Thanks for your prompt answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why it does not suggests you conflicting class names. What you could do is alias type name:

```
using ConfigurationManager = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;
```